# Is there a way to implement fonts not existing in Google fonts into Google Slides/Docs/…?

Tags: google-apps-script, fonts, google-docs, google-slides, google-fonts

A few weeks ago we started the restructure of our corporate design. The problem is the design company used fonts that are not existing in Google fonts. Now we are unable to use our main fonts in presentations and documentations, which is a little problematic. Do you have an idea, how we could solve this problem without completely switching to Microsoft?

I tried different methods, but my script know how is not really there. So mostly everything possible without scripting I tested.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Can't find an official documentation though...

Comment: Nope. Best you can do is try to find similar looking fonts in [Google's library of fonts](https://fonts.google.com/). [Here's a link to a thread discussing why its unlikely we'll see that feature in Google Docs.](https://www.reddit.com/r/googledocs/comments/y7erwt/custom_fonts_any_idea/).

Comment: As a sample, can I ask you about one of your expected fonts? I would like to test it.